# Ruby 2.3.3 application with Rails 4.2.1 and Gem 2.6.14 not working in Centos 6.9

Tags: apache, passenger, ruby-on-rails-4.2, centos6.5

### Ruby 2.3.3 application with Rails 4.2.1, Gem 2.6.14 and passenger 5.1.11 not working in Centos 6.9

**Error in Browser:**

We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.

**Apache error log:**

```
App 3307 stdout: 
App 3307 stdout: 
[ E 2017-11-16 04:58:37.4783 3191/To age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /domainname/httpdocs: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: cc913e9e
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-rMdbsf.html
  Message from application: undefined method `web_console' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x005617ca458e08>
Did you mean?  console (NoMethodError)
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing'
  /domainname/httpdocs/config/application.rb:38:in `<class:Application>'
  /domainname/httpdocs/config/application.rb:15:in `<module:Lobbylights421>'
  /domainname/httpdocs/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
  /domainname/httpdocs/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /domainname/httpdocs/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.11/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.11/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.11/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.11/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.1.11/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'


[ E 2017-11-16 04:58:37.4841 3191/Tb age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 3-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is cc913e9e. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

**Versions Used:**

Ruby  2.3.3 
Rails 4.2.1 
Gem   2.6.14

Comment: It works :)

Edit gem file to
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
end

Change development to production